# Kivy Video Player - Video not loaded

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying this simple example to play a video using Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer


class TestApp(App):
    vid = None

    def replay(self, instance, value):
        if value != "play":
            # self.vid.play = True
            self.vid.state = "play"

    def build(self):
        self.vid = VideoPlayer(source="./S02E02.mp4", state="play")
        # self.vid.bind(state=self.replay)  # When state changes, if not playing, play it
        return self.vid


TestApp().run()
```

But the video is not loaded and played. And I have this as output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/villar/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-08-16_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: null(['video_ffmpeg', 'video_ffpyplayer'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 18.0.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) '>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file ./S02E02.png
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event13
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event13>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event7
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event7>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event13". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event7". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture ./S02E02.mp4
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

The video file `S02E02.mp4` is in the same directory as the python script.

The kivy version I use is 1.10.1, with Python 3.6 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Does anybody knows what is happening?

Answer (score 5):

Use "pip install ffpyplayer"

Answer (score 0):

## Error

```
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event13". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event7". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

## Solution

Add the user to the ‘input’ group:

```
$ sudo adduser $USER input
```

**Note** *you need to log out then back in again for these permissions to be applied.*

Comment: I've added my user to this group but the video still not playing.

Comment: You need to restart your computer. Please post the new Kivy log.

Comment: I did restart the computer, but nothing yet. Here are the logs: https://pastebin.com/yV1XPBCK

Comment: The new log showed that you no longer has permission error on `/dev/input/eventx`. There were two new errors, `[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file ./S02E02.png` and `[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture ./S02E02.mp4`

Comment: But the path is right, the video file is in the same directory as the python script.

Comment: The error is not because it cannot find the folder. There is a problem with the pictures and texture of your mp4 video.

Comment: Try installing gstreamer for audio, video: `sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` and `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Comment: What the heck! Thanks.