# Kivy not loading video

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using the following code using kivy, trying to load a video. I created a new file that didn't have all the extra things I was doing, as to eliminate all the possible complications. I'm new to stack overflow, so if I've done something wrong don't judge...The video is in the same file, and I've tried everything I found online about these kind of errors, I've also installed pillow and ffpyplayer. The error I receive is **[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <ironman.mp4>**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer






class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        video = Video(source='ironman.mp4')
        video.state = "play"
        video.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        video.allow_stretch = True
        video.loaded = True

        return video

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: error occurs as you say but video plays fine

Comment: it's not, the entire window appears white

Comment: try using another video.if not working then upgrade pillow and ffpyplayer and kivy

Comment: i copied exact your code and it worked

Comment: I used another video but still nothing....how's it working in you, it's the same code...hahahha.....coding is very strange....even in embedded systems code sometimes work and sometimes not, and cause is always something weird

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but the `loaded` property of the `Video` is set by the `Video` after the video file is loaded. Changing that property triggers some code in the `Video` class that may not be ready if you set `loaded` yourself. Try just removing the `video.loaded = True` line.

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately

Comment: is there something else that I'll have to have installed that I may not know?

Comment: Try `pip install ffpyplayer`. Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874616/kivy-video-player-video-not-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

Installing ffpyplayer fixed the issue for me. Run

```
pip install ffpyplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Image. Install pillow 8.4.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on W11, installing kivy-deps.gstreamer 0.3.3 fixed it.